# How do I round up a hexadecimal value in Python

Tags: python, hex, rounding

I have a simple algorithm that finds the difference between 2 hex values, I am trying to find a way to round up the values.

For example, if the value is 0x7f8000, I want to round it up to 0x800000.

Is this even possible?

Comment: "round up" based on what? when you "round" in base 10 you round based on values in relation to the decimal point. What would "rounding up" do in context of base 16?

Comment: Maybe you want to find out the largest bit (or hex digit) involved in the number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no particular treatment for hex numbers other than printing them in hex format.

```
>>> def myroundup(n, step):
...     return ((n - 1) // step + 1) * step
...
>>> hex(myroundup(0x7f8000, 0x10000))
'0x800000'
>>> myroundup(998000, 10000) # works with other bases too
1000000
```

If you need rounding down instead, use this:

```
>>> def myrounddn(n, step):
...     return n // step * step
```

And for completeness, rounding to closest step:

```
>>> def myround(n, step):
...     return (n + step // 2) // step * step
```

which you can also define using `myrounddn`:

```
>>> def myround(n, step):
...     return myrounddn(n + step // 2, step)
```

Comment: `n // -step * -step` is simpler than `((n-1) // step + 1) * step`, and has the bonus that it also works for floats.

Answer (score 3):

Rounding up can always be done by adding something which is one smaller than the chunk size and then setting all trailing digits of the chunk size to zero.

In your case, if you want to round up to *n* trailing hex zeros, use this:

```
def round_to_n_trailing_zeros_in_hex(v, n):
  trailing_bits = ((1<<(n*4))-1)
  # ^^^ this is 0b11111111111111111111 == 0x000fffff for n = 5
  return (v + trailing_bits) & ~trailing_bits
```